# Why called "ABA_problem"?

Tags: algorithm, terminology

today I knew ABA problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem

By the way, suddenly, i just like to know why called "ABA" problem? abbreviation?

Comment: The value changes from A, to B, then back to A. Hence, ABA. The examples on Wikipedia already use A and B to describe the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABA is not an acronym and is a shortcut for stating that a value at a
shared location can change from A to B and then back to A :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the problem is related to threads interleaving. So I think it comes as a short textual representation of interleaving. First, run a thread A, then switch to thread B, then get back to thread A.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have two threads, and one is checking a global character whether there's new data:

```
char flag = 'n';

void alarms(){
    while(true){
        if(flag == 'f'){
            start_fire_alarm();
        }
        /* ... some other things, including some waiting ...*/
    }
}

void sensors(){
    while(true){
        if(sensor_alerts_fire()){
            flag = 'f';
        } else {
            flag = 'n';
        }
    }
}
```

Now `alarm` checks the flag, sees `'n'` and everything is fine. Suddenly, a fire starts, and `sensors` sets the flag to `'f'`. But before the operating system gives `alarm` some time to react, the physical sensors break, and they don't alert the fire anymore. `sensors()` sets the flag to `'n'` again, the operating system gives `alarm()` some time and nothing happens.

This is the ABA problem (well, in our case NFN). You don't notice in the first thread that your shared value has changed in-between, although this could be critical. Note that you can exchange `char` with some atomic type and all assignments/tests with atomic ones, the problem would still be the same.